# Zabbix notifying after 2 bad values

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, network-monitoring

I do have a trigger that will fire when external check output will contain "Servers 1/3 UP" or "2/3 UP"  combined with OR. This is one of them:

```
({Zabbix server :server-check.regexp(Servers 1/3 UP, #2)})<>0
```

But it doesn't work. How do I make the trigger fire only when the last two outputs do contain these strings? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `regexp(Servers 1/3 UP, #2)` checks whether any of the last two values have a regular expression `Servers 1/3 UP` in them.

You can instead use function `count(#2, Servers 1/3 UP)` and compare its result to `2`.

Please see [function documentation for Zabbix 3.0](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) for more information. Note that since Zabbix 3.2 regular expression matching is also supported in function `count()` (see [function documentation for Zabbix 3.2](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions)).

Comment: Could you please give me an example of the comparison syntax for a reference? Thanks